# Showing equality $\langle F_v\omega, \tau\rangle = \langle \omega, F^*_v\tau\rangle$

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space with inner product $\langle,\rangle$ and volume element $\mathrm{vol} \in \mathrm{Alt}^n(V)$. Let $v \in \mathrm{Alt}^1(V)$ and $$F_v: \mathrm{Alt}^p(V) \to \mathrm{Alt}^{p+1}(V)$$ be the map $$F_v(\omega)=v\wedge \omega.$$ Show that the map $F^*_v=(-1)^{np} \star \circ F_v \circ \star : \mathrm{Alt}^{p+1}(V) \to \mathrm{Alt}^p(V)$ is adjoint to $F_v$ i.e. $\langle F_v\omega, \tau\rangle = \langle \omega, F^*_v\tau\rangle$.

I'm trying to show this for basis vectors like so. If we pick an orthonormal base $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ for $V$ we get an orthonormal basis $\{\varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{i_p} \mid 1 \le i_1 < \dots < i_p \le n\}$ for $\mathrm{Alt}^{p}(V)$. Now I think It would suffice to show that the equality $$\langle F_v(\varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{i_p}), \varepsilon_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{j_p} \rangle = \langle \varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{i_p}, F^*_v(\varepsilon_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{j_p})\rangle$$

holds for two basis vectors $\varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{i_p}$ and $\varepsilon_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{j_p}$.

Looking at the left-hand side we have $$\begin{align*}\langle F_v(\varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{i_p}), \varepsilon_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{j_p} \rangle &= \langle v \wedge \varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{i_p}, \varepsilon_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{j_p} \rangle \end{align*}$$

but on the right-hand side I don't know what $F^*_v(\varepsilon_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{j_p})$ computes to. I have $$\begin{align*} F^*_v(\varepsilon_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{j_p}) &= (-1)^{np} \circ  \star \circ F_v \circ \star(\varepsilon_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{j_p}) \end{align*}$$

but I don't have a formula for $\star(\varepsilon_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{j_p})$. What I do know is that if we instead use shuffles we have $$\star(\varepsilon_{\sigma(1)} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{\sigma(p)}) = \mathrm{sign}(\sigma) \varepsilon_{\sigma(p+1)} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{\sigma(n)}.$$ So this would give $$\begin{align*} F^*_v(\varepsilon_{\sigma(1)} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{\sigma(p)}) &= (-1)^{np} \circ  \star \circ F_v \circ \star(\varepsilon_{\sigma(1)} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{\sigma(p)}) \\
&= (-1)^{np} \circ  \star \circ F_v(\mathrm{sign}(\sigma) \varepsilon_{\sigma(p+1)} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{\sigma(n)}) \\ &= (-1)^{np} \circ  \star(v \wedge (\mathrm{sign}(\sigma) \varepsilon_{\sigma(p+1)} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{\sigma(n)})) \\ &= (-1)^{np} \circ  \star(v) \wedge \star(\mathrm{sign}(\sigma) \varepsilon_{\sigma(p+1)} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{\sigma(n)})\end{align*}$$

but I'm unfortunatey stuck again as I don't know what $\star(v)$ and $\star(\mathrm{sign}(\sigma) \varepsilon_{\sigma(p+1)} \wedge \dots \wedge \varepsilon_{\sigma(n)})$ evaluates to.

If anyone knows that is this even the right approach I would appreciate the advice?

Comment: You don't need to use a basis to show this. Try writing out $\langle \omega, (-1)^{np}\ast F_v(\ast\tau)\rangle$ and simplifying.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese It's the same issue with this. I end up in trouble with the computation of $(-1)^{np}\ast F_v(\ast\tau)$. What I thought was that it would have been easier with basis elements, but I was wrong.

Comment: You don't need to compute that. Like I said, write out $\langle\omega, (-1)^{np}\ast F_v(\ast\tau)\rangle$. There should be something you can simplify.

Comment: What do you mean by writing out? I don't think I even have a description for $\langle\omega, (-1)^{np}\ast F_v(\ast\tau)\rangle$ without considering basis elements. If we take the basis elements then the inner product would be the determinant of the matrix with entries $\langle \omega_i, \tau_j \rangle$. @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: I've seen only that $$\langle \omega_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \omega_p, \tau_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \tau_p \rangle = \det(\langle \omega_i, \tau_j \rangle)_{ij}).$$

Comment: Ah, that's the issue. The inner product is often defined as $\langle\alpha, \beta\rangle = \alpha\wedge\ast\beta$.

Comment: I see. In that case we have $\langle \omega, (-1)^{np}\ast F_v(\ast\tau)\rangle = \omega \langle \ast (-1)^{np}\ast F_v(\ast\tau)$ and now the aim is to show that $$\langle F_v\omega, \tau\rangle = v \wedge \omega \wedge \ast \tau = \omega \wedge \ast ((-1)^{np}\ast F_v(\ast\tau))$$ which would follow if $$\ast ((-1)^{np}\ast F_v(\ast\tau)) = - v \wedge \ast \tau$$ as then $$v \wedge \omega \wedge \ast \tau =  \omega \wedge -v\wedge \ast \tau = v \wedge \omega \wedge \ast \tau.$$ @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: Looking at the wikipedia page they have $\langle\alpha, \beta\rangle\omega = \alpha\wedge\ast\beta$ for some extra unit vector $\omega$. Can we get rid of this due to orthonormality or why is this not needed in this case? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: Sorry, I should have written $\langle\alpha, \beta\rangle\operatorname{vol} = \alpha\wedge\ast\beta$ (I'm using $\operatorname{vol}$ instead of $\omega$ as you're using that to denote an element of $\operatorname{Alt}^p(V)$). Note that $\ast$ is linear, so $\langle\omega, (-1)^{np}\ast F_v(\ast\tau)\rangle\operatorname{vol} = \omega\wedge(-1)^{np}\ast\ast F_v(\ast \tau)$. Do you how to simplify $\ast\ast$?

Comment: Alright! I know that it's linear and that $\ast \ast = (-1)^{p(n-p)}$, but I'm confused how did you get that $$\ast((-1)^{np} \ast F_v(\ast(\tau))) = (-1)^{np}\ast\ast F_v(\ast \tau)?$$ Shouldn't $\star((-1)^{np})$ give us something?

If what you wrote holds, then $$\omega\wedge(-1)^{np}\ast\ast F_v(\ast \tau) = \omega \wedge (-1)^{2np-p^2} v \wedge \ast \tau$$ @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: $\ast$ is linear so $\ast((-1)^{np}\ast F_v(\ast\tau)) = (-1)^{np}\ast(\ast F_v(\ast\tau))$.

Comment: Okay I can accept that. I've seen that in some elementary cases we would have that $\ast(1) = dx$ for example considering forms in $\mathbb{R}$, but I guess it's different here.

Under this we get to $$\omega \wedge (-1)^{2np - p^2} v \wedge \ast \tau = \left(-1\right)^{1+2np-p^2} v \wedge \omega \wedge \ast \tau$$ which is almost what we wanted except for the sign $\left(-1\right)^{1+2np-p^2}$. Can we get rid of this? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: But you're not taking the Hodge star of $(-1)^{np}$, you're taking the Hodge star of $(-1)^{np}$ multiplied by a form. Your sign is incorrect. It is not true that $\omega\wedge v = -v\wedge\omega$ in general.

Comment: Also, $\ast\ast = (-1)^{p(n-p)}$ on $p$-forms, but $F_v(\ast\tau)$ is not a $p$-form, so your sign there is also off.

Comment: Ah yes it's a $(p+1)$-form as $F_v$ is a map $\mathrm{Alt}^p(V) \to \mathrm{Alt}^{p+1}(V)$. So $\ast\ast = (-1)^{(p+1)(n-(p+1))}$. It seems that there isn't a nice way to get rid of this sign? I was hoping that $\omega\wedge v = -v\wedge\omega$ would have held and that this would have been the key to get rid of the sign. @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: As $\tau$ is a $(p+1)$-form, $\ast\tau$ is an $(n - p - 1)$-form, so $F_v(\ast\tau)$ is an $(n-p)$-form. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are forms of pure degree $a$ and $b$ respectively, then $\alpha\wedge\beta = (-1)^{ab}\beta\wedge\alpha$.

Comment: If $F_v(\ast \tau)$ is an $(n-p)$-form, then $\ast\ast F_v(\ast \tau) = (-1)^{(n-p)p}F_v(\ast \tau)$ since $(n-p)(n-(n-p)) = (n-p)p$. So $(-1)^{np}(-1)^{(n-p)p} = (-1)^{2np -p^2}$ which was what I got before? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: You're correct, of course, my bad. Keep in mind that $(-1)^{2np-p^2} = (-1)^{-p^2} = (-1)^p$ and $\omega\wedge v = (-1)^{1\times p}v\wedge\omega = (-1)^pv\wedge\omega$. Putting it all together, you should be able to finish it off.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks! Only question remaining is that since they asked to show $$\langle F_v\omega, \tau\rangle = \langle \omega, F^*_v\tau\rangle$$, but I think we've actually showed that $$\langle F_v\omega, \tau\rangle\operatorname{vol} = \langle \omega, F^*_v\tau\rangle\operatorname{vol}$$ will the result hold? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: Yes it does. Note that $\operatorname{vol}$ is a non-zero element of $\operatorname{Alt}^nV$ and $\mathbb{R} \to \operatorname{Alt}^nV$, $r \mapsto r\operatorname{vol}$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarise the discussion in the comments regarding a basis free proof.

The map $\mathbb{R} \to \operatorname{Alt}^nV$ given by $r \mapsto r\operatorname{vol}$ is an isomorphism, so it is enough to show that $\langle F_v(\omega), \tau\rangle\operatorname{vol} = \langle\omega, F_v^*(\tau)\rangle\operatorname{vol}$. Using the fact that $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\operatorname{vol} = \alpha\wedge\ast\beta$, we have

\begin{align*}
& \langle\omega, F_v^*(\tau)\rangle\operatorname{vol}\\ 
=&\ \omega\wedge\ast F_v^*(\tau)\\
=&\ \omega\wedge\ast (-1)^{np}\ast F_v(\ast\tau)\\
=&\ \omega\wedge (-1)^{np}\ast\ast F_v(\ast\tau) && (\ast\ \text{is linear})\\
=&\ \omega\wedge (-1)^{np}(-1)^{(n-p)p} F_v(\ast\tau) &&(\ast\ast\ \text{is multiplication by}\ (-1)^{k(n-k)}\ \text{on}\ \operatorname{Alt}^k(V))\\
=&\ \omega\wedge(-1)^{np + np - p^2}F_v(\ast\tau)\\
=&\ \omega\wedge(-1)^pv\wedge\ast\tau &&((-1)^{-p^2} = (-1)^p)\\
=&\ v\wedge\omega\wedge\ast\tau && (\alpha\wedge\beta = (-1)^{ab}\beta\wedge\alpha\ \text{if}\ \alpha\in \operatorname{Alt}^a(V), \beta\in\operatorname{Alt}^b(V))\\
=&\ F_v(\omega)\wedge\ast\tau\\
=&\ \langle F_v(\omega), \tau\rangle\operatorname{vol}.
\end{align*}